# How can i deliver the product to the customer but not the source code in Django?

Tags: python, django, web-deployment

I'm working as a freelance developer for a while. I'm developing a web application using the Django web framework which is using python. Now consider the following scenario and help me out what should I do in such scenario?

The customer wants to provide his own server for deploying the website on the other side I don't want to hand the source code to the customer, Now what should I do? is there any solution?

By the way, based on the aforementioned scenario if the Django does not have such capability, what other frameworks do? (For example, this is the same for PHP frameworks, I think)

Comment: The answer is to stop worrying about pointless things. Just give them the code.

Comment: @DanielRoseman but my friend is succeeded by using the Go language and he just gives them an executable file and now he can offer customers more options, for example they can buy the source code with an extra fee. Also, I think the same is true for Java frameworks.

Comment: It's trivial to decompile Java executables. Although it's true that Go is much harder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my experience this isn't do-able and the way that you protect your intellectual property is via legal agreements with the customer.

```
pip install lawyer
```

Comment: I agree, but the legal agreements in the IT business are not sufficient in some regions. However, thanks for your answer.